# Dynamic Checkboxes not updating correctly

Tags: html, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have dynamic checkboxes that are generated as such

```
  <cfset counter = 0>
     <form name="setPermissions" class="setPermissions" action="" method="post">
     <cfoutput>
          <cfloop query="getUserAccess">
              <input name="Meetings_#Counter#" type="checkbox" />
              <cfset counter = counter + 1>
          </cfloop>
      </cfoutput>
      </form>
```

The `getUserAccess` query has 6 rows, which means that 6 of these checkboxes will be outputted.

To read these and update the table respectively, I'm running the following query

```
<cfloop from="0" to="#getUserAccess.RecordCount#" index="i">
   <cfquery datasource="#Request.dsn#">
        UPDATE table SET 
            <cfif structKeyExists(FORM, 'Meetings_#i#')>
            Meetings = <cfif FORM['Meetings_#i#'] EQ "on">1,<cfelse>0,</cfif>
            </cfif>
        WHERE ID = '#an_ID_that_is_specified#'
   </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

Apologies if this code isn't correct, it works when I'm running it on my page, but there are about 20 of these checkboxes being generated, so I've snipped my code so you can see only one.

Now, this code works great, when I check a box and submit the form, this code will update the database to set the value to 1.

The only problem is, when I uncheck the box, it won't change the value to a 0. This is where I am stuck. Why is it not changing the value to 0 when there is no `on` specified as a form value?

I've done a `<cfdump>` to see if anything was still being passed, but there isn't.

With all of the boxes ticked I get this dump

```
MEETINGS_0   on
MEETINGS_1   on
MEETINGS_2   on
MEETINGS_3   on
MEETINGS_4   on
MEETINGS_5   on
```

With some ticked, the ones which I haven't ticked are not showing up.

However the value is still not updating from a 1 to a 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkbox simply wont submit any value when unchecked (that's how it works). So your query should look closer to this:

```
UPDATE table SET 
    Meetings = <cfif structKeyExists(FORM, 'Meetings_#i#')>1,<cfelse>0,</cfif>
WHERE ID = '#an_ID_that_is_specified#'
```

Comment: YESSSS! I've been smashing my head against a wall for about an hour now, and it was this simple!

Comment: In CF9 you can use ternary statements, so I would reccomend:
` Meetings = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_bit" value="#(structKeyExists(FORM, 'Meetings_' & i))?1:0#">` but its minor change and not neccesary.

Comment: @Dpolehonski looks great! Will look at getting this in, but I might be lazy and not bother :P there's a lot of update conditions in there so might take a while! Thanks for the heads up though!

Comment: just another tip - you can do `<cfset counter++>` to increment a counter

Comment: If it is a `bit` field, you do not even need a ternary operator. structKeyExists returns yes/no which is valid for cf_sql_bit ie `<cfqueryparam value="#structKeyExists(FORM,'Meetings_'& i)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_bit">`.

Answer (score 0):

Sergii already answered the original question. But just to throw another approach out there ...

You could also use lists. Assuming your id's are numeric, give all checkboxes the same name and store the original id's in a hidden field.

```
    <cfoutput query="getUserAccess">
        #meetingID# 
        <input name="SelectedMeetings" type="checkbox" value="#meetingID#" />
    </cfoutput>
    <cfoutput>
        <input name="OriginalMeetings" type="hidden" value="#valueList(getUserAccess.meetingID)#" />
    </cfoutput>
```

On the action page `FORM.SelectedMeetings` will contain a list of all ID's that were selected. Simply take the difference of the two lists to find ID's that were "de-selected".

```
    <cfparam name="FORM.SelectedMeetings" default="" / >
    <cfset FORM.DeSelectedMeetings = replaceList( FORM.OriginalMeetings
                                                 , FORM.SelectedMeetings
                                                 , "") />
```

Then you only need two queries to updates the database instead of six (or however many checkboxes you have). Obviously whichever method you choose, you should wrap all queries in a transaction to ensure they all succeed or fail together.

```
<cfif listLen(trim(FORM.selectedMeetings))>
   <cfquery datasource="#Request.dsn#">
        UPDATE table 
        SET    Meetings  = 1
        WHERE  ID IN ( 
             <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.selectedMeetings#" list="true" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer"> 
        )
   </cfquery>
</cfif>

<cfif listLen(trim(FORM.DeSelectedMeetings))>
   <cfquery datasource="#Request.dsn#">
        UPDATE table 
        SET    Meetings  = 0
        WHERE  ID IN ( 
             <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.DeSelectedMeetings#" list="true" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer"> 
        )
   </cfquery>
</cfif>
```